# Docker-Compose + Django + PostgreSQL + uwsgi + Nginx getting 404 not found

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose, uwsgi

I have recently made some service for practice. I used Docker-Compose, Django, PostgreSQL, uwsgi, Nginx. I try to run in my local machine. 
Here is what my site like when I access it on my server.
[image]

Here is part of about static my settings.py file in the Django 'django_project' root directory.

```
# STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
STATIC_DIR = SRC_DIR.path('static')
STATIC_ROOT = str(SRC_DIR('staticfiles'))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(SRC_DIR('static'))]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Here is my Docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
services:

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    volumes_from:
     - refrigerator
    links:
     - refrigerator:refrigerator
    depends_on:
     - refrigerator

  refrigeratordb:
    image: "postgres:9.6.1"
    container_name: refrigeratordb
    expose:
     - "5432"
    environment:
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "something"
     POSTGRES_USER: "something"
     POSTGRES_DB: "something"

  refrigerator:
    build: .
    container_name: refrigeratormanager
    depends_on:
     - refrigeratordb
    links:
     - refrigeratordb
    volumes:
     - .:/var/www/refrigerator
     - /usr/src/app/static
    command: uwsgi --ini ./refrigerator_manager_uwsgi.ini
    stdin_open: true  
    tty: true
```

Here is my Dockerfile for Django

```
FROM centos/python-36-centos7:latest
USER root

ADD . /var/www/refrigerator/

WORKDIR /var/www/refrigerator
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
```

Here is my Dockerfile for Nginx

```
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./sites-enabled/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Here is my nginx.conf

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name sodwkdrhdjemals.com www.sodwkdrhdjemals.com;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /static;
    }

    location / {
        include     uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        uwsgi_pass  refrigerator:8000;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        return 404;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

Here is my uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/www/refrigerator/
module = refrigerator_manager.wsgi

socket =:8000

chmod-socket = 666

vacuum = true

master = true
```

Here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rest-swagger/', schema_view),
    url(r'^vegetables/?$', VegetablesListCreateAPIView.as_view(), 
name='query_for_vegetables_list'),
    url(r'^vegetables/(?P<vegetable_id>[0-9]+)/?$', 
VegetableRetrieveUpdateDeleteView.as_view(),
        name='retrieve_update_delete_vegetable_item'),
    url(r'^forks/?$', ForksListCreateAPIView.as_view(), 
name='query_for_forks_list'),
    url(r'^forks/(?P<fork_id>[0-9]+)/?$', 
ForkRetrieveUpdateDeleteView.as_view(),
        name='retrieve_update_delete_fork_item'),

    url(r'^.*', api_404, name='api_404'),
]
```

I think the static file is not connected between the nginx container and the Django container. I tried to fix the error for a few days by referring to similar examples of google and StackOverflow, but it is not working well and I need help. Help!

Comment: can you add the `urls.py` files?

Comment: @Jerin Peter George  add my urls.py :)

Comment: @Dean.Kim have you fixed it? Can you update the question with solution so that it would be helpful for others?

Comment: @suraj13k not yet fix it TT